# Nginx per used directory sites configuration

Tags: nginx, wordpress

I have virtual server with 25 hosts with WordPress sites. 
Users need to be able to access their sites via ~username from main domain like this : 
http://subdomain.example.com/~username/ 
which works fine, but if they try to access admin area by adding wp-admin to site : ~username/wp-admin they are redirected to: http://subdomain.example.com/wp-admin/

Any chance someone knows how to set this up with sub-sub domains, like 
username.subdomain.example.com? 
Because some services don't work if you have ~ in site name :(

This is what I have now in default nginx host regarding that:

```
    set $root_dir /home/defaulthost/public_html/;
    rewrite ^(/~[^/]+)$ $1/ redirect;
    rewrite ^/~(?<user>[^/]+)(.+) $2;

if ($user) {
            set $root_dir /home/$user/public_html;
    }
    root $root_dir;
```

Comment: Maybe reading [this](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) and [that](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-wordpress-multisite-with-nginx-on-ubuntu-14-04) helps.

Comment: I've already reconsidered that and I'll used that in the future. But for now I need to resolve this issue with current configuration.

Comment: You need to more precisely tell us the URLs involved. Where are you trying to send them? http://username.subdomain.example.com, http://username.subdomain.com, etc.

Comment: I can handle things on subdomain level so users should have username.subdomain.example.com

Comment: gave up and did what @gf suggested and thats now working fine!